# Best way for Bootstrap customization

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

After going through many articles in the web, we've concluded that there are some different ways to custom twitter bootstrap:

1. Using the http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ site , to predefine settings , before downloading bootstrap
2. Modifying bootstrap less files after downloading bootstrap to our app.
3. Add our own custom.css file which will override the bootstrap css files.

Our question is what's the difference between them, In which case is each of them useful?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can offer that isn't purely opinion-based would be minimizing and maximizing your performance overhead. By pre-configuring your Bootstrap CSS to your specific needs you omit the need to write additional classes or have additional CSS that overrides existing Bootstrap specifications.

That plays out, ultimately, to fewer HTTP requests.  It also reduces the chance that you'll have inconsistent CSS (ie. an override that works on one component, but not another).

...

On the flip side; if you keep with the out-of-the-box Bootstrap you can easily link to it via CDN, which increases the likelihood that your user will already have a cache of the asset on hand.

And at that point we really delve into opinion-based, which isn't really suitable for SO.